# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'FirstMentor'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new with asp.net mvc and having some issues to validate DropDownList with error message mentioned in title.

My controler:

```cs
    public ActionResult SelectMentors(int courseId)
    {

        var mentors = db.Mentor.Where(m => m.CoursesId == courseId).
                                Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = x.FullName,
                                    Text = x.FullName,

                                });

        ViewBag.MentorList = mentors;

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectMentors(StudentSelections model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.StudentSelection.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else

        return View();
    }
```

SelectMentors model

```cs
public class StudentSelections
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail adress")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "1.")]
    public string FirstMentor { get; set; }
```

}

And my View:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMentor, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstMentor, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MentorList, "-- select --", new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstMentor)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Data for mentors retriving from database and passed via ViewBag in View combined with StudentSelections model, error occures when Required filds missing

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean that error is after you make a POST to the server and validation fails. That's because when you validate in your post action, if your `ModelState` is valid then you do your logic and redirect the user to Index action, but what happens when the ModelState is not valid?

Your are returning the view, but your are not filling the data for the mentors list in the ViewBag, so the page fails.

Something like this should work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectMentors(StudentSelections model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.StudentSelection.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    //NOTE: You don't need this 'else' because if everything is OK you'll redirect

    //At this point, an error has occurred.

    //Populate the mentors in the view bag.
    var mentors = db.Mentor.Where(m => m.CoursesId == courseId).
                            Select(x => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.FullName,
                                Text = x.FullName,

                            });
    ViewBag.MentorList = mentors;

    //return the view   
    return View();
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TyJ5He).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not OP problem. OP have problem occures when he GET view

Comment: @teovankot you sure? I assumed by "error occures when Required filds missing" that OP is making a Post, ModelState is invalid and the page will fail to load, because there's nothing in the viewbag for MentorList. I agree that using the model is a better approach but OP should not get any errors using ViewBag in this case. See the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Ok, my bad, could be you right

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

@KarelTamayo has since undeleted his answer, but I'm leaving mine merely for the advice of using a common method both actions can call instead of repeating the same code in each action.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I'm not sure why @KarelTamayo deleted his answer, but that seems to be exactly what's happening here. The OP clearly says that this happens when the form fails validation, which means he's in the POST version of the action. Further, there's nothing wrong with the GET version of the action that would cause this issue, but in the POST version, `ViewBag.MentorList` is never set. *That* is the issue. The code in your GET action that sets `ViewBag.MentorList` needs to be in your POST action, as well. To keep things dry, you can factor it out into another method on your controller:

```
private void SetMentorList()
{
    var mentors = db.Mentor.Where(m => m.CoursesId == courseId).
                            Select(x => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.FullName,
                                Text = x.FullName,

                            });

    ViewBag.MentorList = mentors;
}

public ActionResult SelectMentors(int courseId)
{
    SetMentorList();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectMentors(StudentSelections model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.StudentSelection.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    SetMentorList();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @ChrissPratt I deleted the answer because I thought OP needed to clarify a little bit more about the problem. It wasn't clear when the issue was happening, right? I think that if we're going to help others at least we should not be guessing their problem :-). I then undeleted it so OP could take a look and confirm. Refactoring into SetMentorList method is a great resource, by the way. Specially when you have a lot of lists to populate.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ViewBag` Pass it through the model:

```
public class StudentSelections
{
    //...
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MentorList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SelectMentors(int courseId)
{

    var mentors = db.Mentor.Where(m => m.CoursesId == courseId).
                            Select(x => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.FullName,
                                Text = x.FullName,

                            });

    ViewData.Model = new StudentSelections
    {
       MentorList = mentors
    };

    return View();
}
```

On View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstMentor, 
Model.MentorList, 
"-- select --", 
new { @class = "form-control" })
```